# Small project that adds names,city,hobby, in columns, sorted by hobbies c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, switch-statement

im struggling with my latest project that i have to create, a program that will add Name and Surname, City, and a hobby of the person added, everything has to be sorted by hobbies, at least two columns,
it should looks something like that:

```
|Name and Surname:|City |Born|Hobby|

|1.................|.....|....|fishing|

|2.................|.....|....|fishing|

|3.................|.....|....|books|

|4.................|.....|....||books|
```

.
or Just Name and Surname,city,born(year),hobby <and its just sorted in hobbies

Menu:

1. Add Person
2. Remove Person
3. Exit Program
   Choose: ... (1 to 3)

im kinda new to programming so i will write down what i've done so far.

```
float x[50],y[50];
int choose;

  int main()
{
  cout<<"Name and surname: "<<endl;
   cout<<x;

    for (;;)
    {
        int i=0,
        cout<<"Menu :"<<endl;
        cout<<"1. Add person"<<endl;
        cout<<"2. Remove person"<<endl;
        cout<<"3. Exit program"<<endl;

        cout<<"Choose by number: ";
        cin>>choose;
        switch(choose);
        {
        case 1:
            {
            cout<<"Write Name and Surname: ";
            cin>>x[i]<<i++;
            break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

thats kinda it, i still don't know how i could remove people from list and how to sort it by hobbies
any help would be awesome, will update if i can make it by myself

Comment: please focus on one specific question. Fix your current code before you add more. It has quite some errors https://godbolt.org/z/M8vzf3. Fix them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of programming these days involves looking up existing libraries and frameworks. There are a lot of already-written objects to help you. In particular, you might want to study `std::list` or `std::vector` from a site such as HTTP://www.cppreference.com . These classes have members to inspect, add, or delete items from lists. You probably want to create a `struct` or a `class` to represent each person, and then have a list of those.

For example:

```
struct Person
{
  std:string firstName;
  std::string lastName;
}

std::vector<Person> myList;
```

This is just the barest hint at how you would begin.